# ((xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,} works on regexpal.com, but not on jsfiddle.net

Tags: javascript, regex

So this regular expression contained in "pattern" below, is only supposed to match what I say in the comment below (with the most basic match being 1 letter follow by a dot, and then two letters)

```
var link = "Help"
// matches www-data.it -- needs at least (1 letter + '.' + 2 letters )
var pattern = '((xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,}';
var re2 = new RegExp('^' + pattern, 'i');


// if no http and there is something.something
if (link.search(re2) == 0)
{
    link = link;
}
```

When I test this code @ http://regexpal.com/ it works e.g. only something.something passes.

When I test it at JSFiddle and in production it matches more than it should, e.g. "Help" matches.
http://jsfiddle.net/2jU4D/

what's the deal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should construct the regular expression with native regex syntax:

```
var re2 = /^((xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,}/i;
```

In particular, the `\.` in the regular expression will look like just plain `.` by the time you call `new RegExp()`.  The string grammar also uses backslash for quoting, so the backslash will be "eaten" when the expression is first parsed as a string.

Alternatively:

```
var pattern = '((xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\\.)+[a-z]{2,}';
var re2 = new RegExp('^' + pattern, 'i');
```

Doubling the backslash will leave you with the proper string to pass to the RegExp constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the breakdown of what it matches. I would replace all the capture groups with  non-capture groups. And put all the anchors in the body of a regex (don't append later).

The regex is valid, don't know about its delimeters or the way you are using it.
Pay attention to the required parts and you will see its not matching correctly, but not
I don't think because of the regex.

```
 (                         # (1 start)
      ( xn-- )?                 # (2), optional capture 'xn--'
      [a-z0-9]+                 # many lower case letters or digits
      ( - [a-z0-9]+ )*          # (3), optional many captures of '-' followed by many lower case letters or digits
      \.                        # a dot '.'
 )+                        # (1 end), overwrite this capture buffer many times
 [a-z]{2,}                 # Two or more lower case letters
```

Comment: Pointy already pointed out the cause 13 minutes ago. Perhaps you missed it?

Comment: I wasn't reading his post, but typing a comments. Something you missed?

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't expect anyone with more than 50 rep to post a comment as an answer instead of as a comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, you lost me partner. Want to explain that better.

Comment: `typing a comments` = `# (1 end), overwrite this capture buffer many times` : The answer I posted `its delimeters`, did you miss it?